# What versions describe Arjuna blinding Bhagadatta?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna

According to this [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20050828143008/http://members.cox.net/apamnapat/entities/Bhagadatta.html) it says that Arjuna blinded Bhagadatta but in BORI Arjuna kills Bhagadatta without doing that, whereas in KMG it is described that after his death, the handkerchief that kept his wrinkles in place to avoid blindness He fell silent but only after Arjuna killed him.

But obviously there has to be a source that describes Arjuna doing such a thing, so my question is, in what versions of the Mahabharata is Arjuna described as blinding Bhagadatta?